# Update command not working but there is no Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table named `MesaiBilgileri` and columns `Id`, `AdiSoyadi`, `Mesai`, `MesaiTarih`...

I'd pick the info from table named `PersonelBilgileri` with this code:

```
private void cboxAdSoyadMesai_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string secilipersonel = cboxAdSoyadMesai.Text;
    baglan.Open();

    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select *from PersonelBilgileri WHERE AdiSoyadi = '" + secilipersonel + "'", baglan);

    SqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

    while (oku.Read())
    {
        lbId.Text = oku["Id"].ToString();
    }

    baglan.Close();
}
```

I'd use invisible label to take items Id for write another table...

Then with this values I'd go to another table and update that table with this code:

```
private void mesaiekle()
{
    string secilitarih = dtpMesai.Value.ToShortDateString(); //combobox for pick date
    string secilipersonel = cboxAdSoyadMesai.Text; //combobox for pick employee
    int mesaiId;
    mesaiId = Convert.ToInt32(lbId.Text); //another table's Id value from invisible label...

    baglan.Open();

    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MesaiBilgileri SET Id = '"+ mesaiId +"' , AdiSoyadi = '"+ secilipersonel +"' ,  Mesai = '" + cboxSaatMesai.Text + "' , MesaiTarih = @tarih", baglan);
    komut.Parameters.Add("@tarih", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = secilitarih;

    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

    baglan.Close();
}
```

With this code when I push the save button;

```
private void btnMesaiEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((cboxSaatMesai.Text == string.Empty) && (cboxAdSoyadMesai.Text == string.Empty))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Eklemek İstediğiniz Mesai Bilgilerini Seçmek Zorundasınız", "HATA!!"); 
    }
    else
    {
        mesaiekle();
        MessageBox.Show("" + cboxAdSoyadMesai.Text + " İçin Mesai Eklendi", "Mesai Ekleme Durumu");
    }
}
```

When I push the save button I see the confirmation messagebox but table is not updated... There is no error... I'm new at coding so what can I do?

Sorry for my English :/

Comment: Using the debugger see what is the value of `komut.CommandText` before executing this line: `komut.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: why are you using parameters on a dynamic query?

Comment: Use a try/catch at least in debugging to make sure there is no error. Also inspect the CommandText of the command to and see if it will update anything when run directly in SSMS. And, building SQL that way open you to SQL injection which you should Google and not ignore just because you are focused on making it work.

Comment: @McNets I dont know i just learn that :)

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in update query, is that OK? Can you use sql profiler and see what updare query is being executed? Try running the same query from SSMS and see if ot updates any records. Did you debug the code?

Comment: Add `secilitarih` to the update sentence just like the other variables.

Comment: `+ "' , MesaiTarih = secilitarih", baglan);`

Comment: And remove `komut.Parameters.Add("@tarih.....` sentence

Comment: @McNets when i add secilitarih like '"+secilitarih+"' error The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @Chetan i debug the code but there is no error... i'll try to try/catch...

Comment: what field type is MesaiTarih ?

Comment: `+ "' , MesaiTarih = cast(" + secilitarih.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") + " as datetime), baglan);` Use a date format according to your db server

Comment: In your update query, try converting the mesaiId variable to string: mesaiId.Tostring()

Comment: @McNets "yyyy-mm-dd" cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh not working :/

Comment: isn't secilitarih a DateTime too?

Comment: @McNets string secilitarih = dtpMesai.Value.ToShortDateString();

Comment: `+ "' , MesaiTarih = cast(" + secilitarih + " as datetime), baglan);`

Comment: Sorry.. yeah '*FROM' = '* FROM'
Ok how about the UPDATE statement? It seems to be setting every record in your table. Shouldn't there be a WHERE clause in there

Comment: Ahh I think you have an INDENTITY 1 set on your primary key of MesaiBilgileri table. You cannot UPDATE auto primary keys

Comment: And you should use TRY {} CATCH {} or USING() as much as possible

Comment: @McNets  Incorrect syntax near '.2017'. code is: `Mesai = '" + cboxSaatMesai.Text + "' , MesaiTarih = cast(" + secilitarih + " as datetime)", baglan);`

Comment: @Fernando68 there is no Identity set on MesaiBilgileri table but Personel Bilgileri Id column is have Identity...

Comment: **You know what:** if it doesn't error out, It means the update query does go through so check your connection string, you might be hitting another copy of your database instead of the one you desire. This sometimes happens when you focus too much on syntax and forget about what database you are connecting to.

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh but i can take value from table for comboboxes...

Comment: Really you want to update all rows in the Table?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string secilitarih = dtpMesai.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Build your update command without use parameters:

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MesaiBilgileri SET Id = '"
                                  + mesaiId 
                                  +"' , AdiSoyadi = '"
                                  + secilipersonel 
                                  +"' ,  Mesai = '" 
                                  + cboxSaatMesai.Text 
                                  + "' , MesaiTarih = " 
                                  + "cast ('" + secilitarih  + "' as datetime) "
                                  + ", baglan);
```

Add a message box or a breakpoint to check the command text.

```
MessageBox.Show(komut.CommandText);
```

If you have some problem with date format change `secilitarih` to:

```
string secilitarih = dtpMesai.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Commandtext is looking good i have what values i want... but MesaiBilgileri table is empty... try refresh and reconnect but its empty...

Comment: Before to UPDATE you should INSERT some row!!

Comment: OMG! i try to update nothing! i need to use INSERT INTO right?

Comment: `INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3, ...) VALUES (Val1, Val2, Val3, ...)`

Comment: @McNets: Dont try to mislead a newbie, hope that you are aware of SQL Injection, and  integer values need not to enclose within single quotes if you are using concatenated queries.

Comment: I was try to Update nothing... :/ sorry guys really :/

Comment: @YunusEmreAltanay, @un-lucky means that by using text command instead of parametrized queries, allow sql injection, something like `select a,b, from table where field = delete from your table` You must take care of your sql command construction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to note several things here. You are dealing with different datatypes in this single query, The variable `mesaiId` is defined as integer(not sure how the field is defined in the database). you need not to pass a integer value within a pair of single quotes. And why some values are parameters? why not the whole query params? Make a try with this:

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MesaiBilgileri SET Id = @mesaiId, AdiSoyadi =@secilipersonel,Mesai = @cboxSaatMesai, MesaiTarih = @tarih", baglan);

komut.Parameters.Add("@mesaiId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mesaiId;
komut.Parameters.Add("@secilipersonel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = secilipersonel;
komut.Parameters.Add("@cboxSaatMesai", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboxSaatMesai.Text;
komut.Parameters.Add("@tarih", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = secilitarih;

komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note :- Keep in mind that it will update all rows in the table since you have not specified any condition, if you need to update specific rows then you have to add `Where Id = @mesaiId` or something like that